# read more/ read less

Tags: jquery

I don't know what is wrong with my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var adjustheight = 80;
var moreText = "+ read more";
var lessText = "- less text";

$("div.posted_post .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
$("div.posted_post").append('[...]');

$("a.show").text(moreText);

$(".show").toggle(function()
    {
        $(this).find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
        $(this).text(lessText);
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $(this).text(moreText);
    });
});
```

the html looks like this:

```
<div class="posted_post">
    <div class="more-block">
        <p>The Content</p>
            <a class="show"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i load the page the show more button is shown but in a second it gets hidden what is wrong here?

Comment: your html is missing the a.show part. Also I'm quite puzzled with the $(this).find(".more-block") which suggests a.show engulfes the whole block

Comment: Not able to understand what exactly you are trying to do. better if you provide more information (like body tag data)

Comment: Some css would be helpful with a bit more html. I think it's likely a css issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle you are trying to use has been removed in jQuery 1.9 (deprecated since 1.8)

see http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

So by calling toggle, you are really toggling your element (if you are using jq1.9)

BTW :

```
$(this).find(".more-block")
```

won't return anything.

It should be :

```
$(this).closest(".more-block")
```

You may try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var adjustheight = 80;
var moreText = "+ read more";
var lessText = "- less text";

$("div.posted_post .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
$("div.posted_post").append('[...]');

$("a.show").text(moreText);

$(".show").click(function()
    {
        if($(this).text()===lessText)
        {
            $(this).closest(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
            $(this).text(moreText);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).closest(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
            $(this).text(lessText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip... well how should i change the toggle function?

Comment: well now it toggles between the read more and read less text... but the div desn't extands at all:-??

Comment: @PaulHarbuz well, the div does extend here : http://jsfiddle.net/CVVJ5/ (don't know if it is the desired behavior)

Comment: @PaulHarbuz well seems to work (provided the link is at the start of the div, otherwise, ti gets hidden) see http://jsfiddle.net/CVVJ5/2/

Comment: yeah you are right! thank you... i will solve the problem.. i accepted your answer.thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually creating the button. You need to do

```
$('<a class="show"/>').text(moreText).appendTo('.posted_post').
```

If you have more than one post though, you need to loop over them to create the more links. Eg:

```
$("div.posted_post").each(function () {
     // create more links and set CSS.
```

Comment: yeah i have the anchor but i forgot to copy and paste it

Comment: when i use each... it makes the botton toggle for once for eachpost and then stop ... WEIRD!